# Is there any temple where deities are Brahma, Vishnu and Maheshwara?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, temple, brahma

Is there any temple where deities are Brahma, Vishnu and Maheshwara all the three supreme gods are worshipped at once?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, there are a few.

#### Temples of historical significance

The very famous [Prambanan temple at Java, Indonesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prambanan). This very old temple (and UNESCO world heritage site) from 9th century is dedicated to the trimurti. There are three temples, one for each Brahma, Vishnu and Maheshwara, there. Also, there are separate temples for their vahanas as well.

[image: Image of the temple from Wikipedia]

---

The main deity at [the Elephanta Caves, Mumbai, India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephanta_Caves), (which is also a UNESCO world heritage site), is a large stone sculpture of trimurti.

> The three heads represent three essential aspects of Shiva: creation, protection, and destruction. The right half-face (west face) shows him holding a lotus bud, depicting the promise of life and creativity. This face is symbolism for Brahma, the creator or Uma or Vamadeva, the feminine side of Shiva and creator. The left half-face (east face) is that of a moustached young man. This is Shiva as the terrifying Aghora or Bhairava, the chaos creator and destroyer. This is also known as Rudra-Shiva, the Destroyer. The central face, benign and meditative Tatpurusha, resembles the preserver Vishnu.

[image]

---

#### Temples where worship is still being carried out today

The [Thripaya Trimurti Temple at Thrissur, India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thripaya_Trimurti_Temple) is another temple dedicated to trimurti. Here, the three deities are worshipped at once, as they are all placed on the same pedestal.

> Thripaya Trimurti Temple is a Hindu temple in Irinjalakuda, Thrissur in Kerala, India. It is the only temple in the world where the Trimurti sit in one pedestal in one sanctum sanctorum.

---

As [@NogShine](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/5212/sarvabhouma) mentioned in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42413816#42413816), the [Mithrananthapuram Trimurti Temple at Thiruvananthapuram, Kerala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mithrananthapuram_Trimurti_Temple)  is also another place where the trimurti are worshipped together.

Comment: I am proud of having this temple in Indonesia. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a very good answer. Keep it up! :)

Comment: Late reply to this post but there is 1 temple in Jodhpur (Rajasthan) where all 3 gods are worshipped together (Brahma, Vishnu and Mahesh) also with surya dev and mahalakshmi devi. Unfortunately someone stole the murti of Lord vishnu from that temple.

Comment: @Leothelion feel free to add it as an answer, if you have supporting links/articles. :)

Comment: @BhargavRao sorry but did not get supporting links/articles? If you mean details about temple, then i can share images as i am living next to that temple and even i did puja for years there. but not sure if user wants to know about temple with all gods so i commented rather then answer.

Answer (score 19):

There is one temple of Trimurties i.e. Lord Brahma, Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva, in Uthamarkoil, a village in the outskirts of **Tiruchirappalli** in the South Indian state of **Tamil Nadu**. The temple is called  [**Uthamar Kovil**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uthamar_Kovil)

[image]

---

The temple is one of the few historical temples in India where the Hindu trimurti, Vishnu, Shiva, and Brahma are housed in the same premises

The temple is glorified in the Divya Prabandha.

---

Answer (score 11):

In a place called [Sucheendram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suchindram) near Kanyakumari of India, Lord Brahma, Lord Vishnu and Lord Maheshwara are in a single form called '[Sthanumalayan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanumalayan_Temple)' and worshipped in that form.

From Wiki:

> The main deity of the temple is Lord Shiva, Lord Vishnu and Lord Brahma in a single form called Sthanumalyam. This 17th-century temple is famous for its architectural grandeur. The seven-storey white Gopuram is visible from the distance. Its 40 m facade is covered with sculptures of Hindu deities.
>
> The place got the name of Suchindrum from the Sthala Purana. Hindu mythological legend has it that king of devas, Indra got relieved of a curse at the place of the main linga in the temple. The term "Suchi" in Suchindrum is believed to have derived from the Sanskrit meaning that stands for "purify". Accordingly, Lord Indra is supposed to visit the temple for performing "Ardhajama Pooja", or worship, at midnight every day.

Answer (score 0):

I am from Maharashtra. Forgive me if you already know this, but Lord Dattatreya(God Datta Digambar) is unified version of Lord Brahma, Vishnu and Mahesh. There are lot of temples in Maharashtra of Lord Datta.
You can worship Lord Datta to pray to all 3.

You can read more about Lord Dattatreya here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dattatreya

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).